# Can Apple Remote app wake up an Apple TV 2?

Tags: appletv, remote.app

Is it possible to wake up an Apple TV 2 using the Apple Remote app on an iPhone or iPad rather than using the remote that comes packaged with the Apple TV 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as soon as you start the Remote app and tap the 'Menu' button, the Apple TV will wake up.

Comment: I finally was able to try this and it worked like you said. Life will be that much easier now that I won't have to hunt down that tiny little remote when I need it.  Geaux Tigers! ;)

Comment: Yeah, if I had a dollar for every time I lost my Apple remote down the side of the couch... Also, War Eagle!

Answer (score 0):

If your Apple TV is using WiFi, it may only work with an Apple Airport. It's more a matter of your router supporting the Bonjour sleep proxy service. It needs to send the wake up packet to your Apple TV when it sees the remote app trying to poll and see which devices are present on the network to control remotely.

- [About Wake on Demand](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3774)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_Sleep_Proxy